# How to delete a table row defined by a dropdown list option submitted (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form with dropdown menu that the options populated from 'nama_guru' row inside 'dropdown_list' table.
What i'm trying to do is deleting a row of 'nama_guru' column that table based on which option of dropdown menu is submitted.

Heres some of my code.

Dropdown menu

```
<div class="left-inner-addon">
    <select input type="text" name="nama_guru" value="<?php echo $nama_guru ?>" class="form-control" id="inputNama" >
        <?php 
        foreach($nama_guru as $row)
        { 
            echo '<option value="'.$row->nama_guru.'">'.$row->nama_guru.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Controller

```
function data_kuesioner_save($idx = '', $where =''){
    if($_POST){
        $nama_guru          = $this->input->post('nama_guru');

        if($status == 'baru'){
            $data = array(
                'nama_guru' => $nama_guru,
            );
            $sukses = '
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <strong>Sukses!</strong> Data anda telah tesimpan.
                </div>
            ';
            $this->siswamodel->deletedropdowndata($nama_guru);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('sukses', $sukses);
            $this->siswamodel->insertdata('data_kuesioner',$data);
            redirect('siswa/data_kuesioner_view');
        }
    }
}
```

Model

```
class Siswamodel extends CI_Model {

    function insertdata($tabel, $data){
        return $this->db->insert($tabel,$data);
    }

    function deldata($tabel,$where){
        return $this->db->delete($tabel,$where);
    }

    function updatedata($tabel,$data,$where){
        return $this->db->update($tabel,$data,$where);
    }

    function selectdata($where = ''){
        return $this->db->query("select * from $where;");
    }

    function printjointable($where = ''){
        return $this->db->query("select * from $where;");
    }

    function deletedropdowndata($idx){
        $this->db->where('nama_guru', $idx);
        $this->db->delete('isi_dropdown1');
    }
}
```

Comment: if i remember you correctly, you are making the questionnaire right? if you intend to have multiple users, or even foreign keys, you really shouldn't be deleting teachers. doing it this way means that once a questionnaire is completed the teacher won't exist anymore for someone else to fill out a questionnaire on him/her. idk this might be desired in your case...

Comment: in relation to your question: you need to specify what is happening that shouldn't be. remove the redirect. see if there are any errors. do some troubleshooting, and update your question.

Comment: well i decided to give every user its own table just for populating a dropdown list. is that even effective, i dont know lol

Comment: definitely not. here is a simple scenario. you have a table called `teachers` where teachers are identified by a column called `id` (`teacher.id`), and a table called `questionnaire` with all the questionnaire columns plus `teacher_id` and `user_id`. `user_id` is a foreign key to `users.id` table, and `teacher_id` is a foreign key to `teacher.id`. So say you have teachers with ids 1,2,3. and in the questionnaire table user 1 submitted 1 questionnaire. this particular questionnaire user 1 filled out is linked to the teacher_id.

Comment: thus you just have to query the questionnaire table now where `SELECT teacher_id FROM questionnaire WHERE user_id = 1`. You'll get an array with one item, say teacher 1. Then you just remove that teacher from the main array of teachers that populates the dropdown for that user

Comment: this make perfect sense, thank you for your advice. i'll try to implement it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SOF!

First we need to correct our dropdown. We don't give input type to our select DOM element its already set to "select" which means a dropdown. Secondly the value attribute is for options for not the element itself. Please see the following code.

```
<div class="left-inner-addon">
<select name="nama_guru" class="form-control" id="inputNama" >
    <?php 
    foreach($nama_guru as $row)
    { 
        echo '<option value="'.$row->nama_guru.'">'.$row->nama_guru.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
</select>
</div>
```

Alright, we have our markup fixed. now work on delete part. Without a form we can't do that I believe you have something like below which encapsulates rest of your markup.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  // Form Content ...
</form>
```

When we don't mention anything in action, the form submits to itself, which means we can catch the request in the same function we are using to output the form.

Lets work on your Controller function

```
public function data_kuesioner_view()
{
    if($_POST)
    {
        // Delete data from table
        $this->siswamodel->deletedropdowndata($_POST);
        // Success Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Congratulations, Data removed.');
        // Redirect to the form
        redirect(base_url().'siswa/data_kuesioner_view');
    }
    else
    {
        // load form view
        $this->load->view('form');
    }
}

// Model function

public function deletedropdowndata($data)
{
    $this->db->where('nama_guru', $data['nama_guru']);
    $this->db->delete('isi_dropdown1');
    return true;
}
```

Let's display our flash message

Above the form Just place below code;

```
<?php if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('success'))){?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
               <?php print_r($this->session->flashdata('success'));?>
        </div>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, ill make some modifications according to your advice

Answer (score 0):

return query

```
function deletedropdowndata($idx){
  return $this->db->where('nama_guru', $idx)->delete('isi_dropdown1');
  }
```